# Better way to fill a div with content and then use jQuery to fix height?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to find a better way of fixing the maximum height of a div once it has been populated. I search through all the possible contents for the largest list item (as only one will be shown at once), and then fix the height so that the wrapper always stays at the tallest it needs to be. This is what I've got so far. It's a bit messy and I'm curious as to whether there's a neater/more efficient way of doing it. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
var height = 0;

//populate div
$('.items').html('<ul><li>list item 1</li><li>list item 2<br />newline</li></ul>'); //etc 

for(i=0;i<$('li').length;i++);
{
    if($('li').eq(i).height() > height)
    {
        height = $('li').eq(i).height();
    }
}

//fix height of div 
$('.items').height(height);

$('li').hide().first().show();
```

Comment: i think not setting a height property will solve this..have you tried? this is obviously not how a code suppose to look like when the only thing you need is to resize div height

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the height to auto with css?

```
.items{
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that will work. I'm searching for the largest contents, and then fixing the wrapper to that size. I'll edit the question as it's a little unclear.

Comment: Unless your inner contents / `items` have fixed or absolute positioning, `height: auto` should work: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rG4nS/1/).

Comment: Setting the height to auto worked and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rG4nS/2/) also worked. Give both a try.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if this is what you mean, but here is something im doing in a project:
first: load all content

```
<div id="content">
    content goes here
<div>
```

then i use a script:

```
<script>
   var element = document.getElementById('content');
   element.style.width= element.offsetWidth + "px";
   element.style.height= element.offsetHeight + "px";
</script>
```

go sure you place this script **after** the element you want to fix the height/width.
if you now change the innerHTML with another function, the height and width will not change.

together:

```
<div id="content">
    you might want to load something dynamic here with javascript or PHP
<div>
<script>
   var element = document.getElementById('content');
   element.style.width= element.offsetWidth + "px";
   element.style.height= element.offsetHeight + "px";
</script>
```

note: since this is no function, the script will execute when the page loads and cannot be called later

if you want to make the height/width larger, dont forget to use brackets avoid the automatic type conversion:

```
<script>
   var element = document.getElementById('content');
   element.style.width= (element.offsetWidth + 5) + "px";
   element.style.height= (element.offsetHeight + 5) + "px";
</script>
```

i hope this helped you :)